# How to get the $_SESSION info with a specific session_id() in PHP?

Tags: php, session

So far I can only get session info of the **current** one out of `$_SESSION`,

how can I investigate the session info of **arbitary** `session_id()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[session_id()](https://www.php.net/session_id) is the answer.

```
session_id(whateverhereidyouneedhere);
session_start();
```

> If id is specified, it will replace
> the current session id. session_id()
> needs to be called before
> session_start() for that purpose.